# unitTest method animate() in AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-directive

I have a directive:

```
myApp.directive('scrollOn', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {

       angular.element("body, html").animate({ scrollTop: offset.top - 12 }, scrollSpeed);

    }
  }
});
```

How would I unit test `$("body").animate({scrollTop: $elm.offset().top}, "slow");`

Any help would be appreciated.

**Updated**
I don't have click in my directive, instead i am trying to scroll to a specific element on HTML page using this directive. I haven't posted the entire code of directive. I am using angular.element().animate. How can i unit test this?

Comment: This is not a unitTest. You are looking for a functional UI test. Maybe an End-to-End test. What you like to test?

Comment: This is a e2e test. You want to trigger the click event on the element and the test if the offset of the element is has moved. use protractor